# how to access value for dictionary data frame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in key value sequence but i am able to handle acces a particular key value in this dataframe.

> how can i access a indiviual dataframe at time like kwh1

`

```
 {'Kwh1': '3750.13', 'Kwh2': '3456.04', 'Kwh3':...
    {'Kwh1': '3750.14', 'Kwh2': '3456.04', 'Kwh3':...
    {'Kwh1': '3750.15', 'Kwh2': '3456.04', 'Kwh3':...
    {'Kwh1': '3750.15', 'Kwh2': '3456.04', 'Kwh3':...
    {'Kwh1': '3750.16', 'Kwh2': '3456.04', 'Kwh3':...
                               ...
    {'Kwh1': '3751.94', 'Kwh2': '3456.04', 'Kwh3':...
    {'Kwh1': '3751.95', 'Kwh2': '3456.04', 'Kwh3':...
    {'Kwh1': '3751.95', 'Kwh2': '3456.04', 'Kwh3':...
    {'Kwh1': '3751.96', 'Kwh2': '3456.04', 'Kwh3':...
    {'Kwh1': '3751.97', 'Kwh2': '3456.04', 'Kwh3':...
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are dictionaries in column `col` use:

```
df['Kwh1'] = df['col'].str.get('Kwh1')
```

If there are string repr of dictionaries in column `col` use:

```
import ast

df['Kwh1'] = df['col'].apply(ast.literal_eval).str.get('Kwh1')
```

If need all keys to columns:

```
df1 = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df['col']))
df1 = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df['col'].apply(ast.literal_eval)))
```